# SQL Server 2008: How to show results all at once after query ends?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to ask if there is a way to show results (all at once) just after the query ends execution? In other words, I dont want to see "Partial" records on the way of query execution.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you querying in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Why do you care?  If it's in SQLMS, its not like displaying them is slow you down, and if it's in your app, you can complete control.

Comment: Thank you Eric.
What do you mean by "and if it's in your app, you can complete control"? Actually the main reason for my question is that i think if i got all results (especially for huge amount of data like 500000 records) just only after all records there this will help my app run much faster ...

Answer (score 0):

Would wrapping your SQL statements into a single transaction help?